# How to search an array for matching property from another array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `products` array that looks like this:

```TypeScript
const products = 
[
    { product: 'prod_aaa', name: 'Starter' },
    { product: 'prod_bbb', name: 'Growth' },
    { product: 'prod_ccc', name: 'Elite' },
];
```

And a `subscriptions` array that looks something like this:

```TypeScript
const subscriptions = 
[
    {
        "status":"active",
        "product": "prod_aaa",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "status":"active",
        "product": "prod_2342352345",
        "quantity": 1,
    }
];
```

Now I want to check the `subscriptions` array to find the first occurance of a matching product from the `products` array, and output the **name** of the product  it finds (Starter/Growth/Elite).

I imagine it needs something like `subscriptions.filter()`. But I don't know how to make it give me the **name** of the product it finds.

I cannot change the `subscriptions` input, but I can change the `plans` input if needed.

What is the best way to do this?

P.S. My code is written in TypeScript

Comment: If `products = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]` and `subscriptions = ["E", "C", "B", "D", "A"]`, do you want the answer to be based off of `"A"` or `"C"`?

Comment: @Samathingamajig it should be based off "C" because that is the first occurance in the `subscriptions` array that matches a product in `products`.

Comment: @TinyTiger I've updated my answer with a filter implementation as well if that is what you are looking for specifically. In both cases you can 'Run code snippet' and see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned filter(), but it should only be used when you are looking to use the array returned by it. Since you are only looking for the name, you would be better served with a for loop.

```js
const products = [{
    product: 'prod_aaa',
    name: 'Starter'
  },
  {
    product: 'prod_bbb',
    name: 'Growth'
  },
  {
    product: 'prod_ccc',
    name: 'Elite'
  },
];

const subscriptions = [{
    "status": "active",
    "product": "prod_aaa",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "status": "active",
    "product": "prod_2342352345",
    "quantity": 1,
  }
];

function find() {
  for (const product of products) {
    for (const subs of subscriptions) {
      if (product.product === subs.product) {
        return product.name;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(find())
```

Edit: If you are absolutely looking for something with filter(). Here is what will help:

```js
const products = [{
    product: 'prod_aaa',
    name: 'Starter'
  },
  {
    product: 'prod_bbb',
    name: 'Growth'
  },
  {
    product: 'prod_ccc',
    name: 'Elite'
  },
];

const subscriptions = [{
    "status": "active",
    "product": "prod_aaa",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "status": "active",
    "product": "prod_2342352345",
    "quantity": 1,
  }
];

let result = products.filter(prod => {
  return subscriptions.some(sub => prod.product === sub.product)
})[0].name;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to Avneesh's approach I have traversed through the `subscriptions` array first.

```js
// find a first subscription for which product is found in the products array.

let requiredSub = subscriptions.find(sub => products.some(p => p.product === sub.product))

let requiredProduct = requiredSub.product
```

Javascript `Array.some` method mdn reference -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: This does not return the `name` value.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel noted